# How do I remove the square brackets from the list? By using the strip function

Tags: python

```
 calendar = []

f = open("calendar.txt","w")

while True:
    choice = input ("enter a,b,c,d or e")
    if choice == "e":
        print ("you have quitted this program")
        break #to quit the entire program
    if choice == "a":
        newevent = input ("enter the name of an event you want to add")
        calendar.append ([newevent]) 
        y= int(input("enter the year of your event"))
        m = int(input("enter the month of your event"))
        d = int(input("enter the day of your event"))
        h = int(input("enter the hour of your event"))
        mi = int(input("enter the minute of your event"))
        date = (y,m,d,h,mi)

    for i in range (0,len(calendar)):
        f = open("calendar.txt","r")
        st = f.readlines()
    
    for y in range (0,len(st)):
        st[y] = st[y].strip("\n")
        st[y]= st[y].split(",")
        st[y][1]=int(st[y][1])
        f.close()

    for x in range (0,len(calendar)):
        if calendar[x][0]== newevent:
            calendar[x].append (date)
            print (calendar)
```

this is my output:

```
enter a,b,c,d or ea
enter the name of an event you want to addswim
enter the year of your event2020
enter the month of your event2
enter the day of your event2
enter the hour of your event2
enter the minute of your event2
[['swim', (2020, 2, 2, 2, 2)]]
enter a,b,c,d or e
```

how do I remove the square brackets around it?

Comment: Print the individual elements, instead of the entire list at once.

Comment: There is no need to show all of your code for the purpose of your question: just show the print function where you print the list, the output you get, and the output you want. The rest of the code just distracts.

Comment: import numpy as np
list(np.array(list).flat)
Convert 2d array to 1d array . Remove the brackets

Answer (score 0):

```py
print(",".join(list))
```

or

```py
print(str(list)[1:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have a list inside a list. which is normal since a calendar can be shown as a list of events, each one composed of one name, and one date, that can be stored as a list.

To print the last event you added to your calendar, you can use `print(calendar[-1])`.

They are some problems in your program :

- At the very begining, you open your calendar in write mode as `f`, then you re-open it in read mode, as `f` too, whithout calling `close()` on it.
- When you open the file in read mode, you do it in a for loop, and re-assign the same variable each time. This is useless.

To make your program simpler :

- Don't open the file at the begining.
- When the user enters the name of the event, store it in a list with the date before inserting it in the calendar, so you don't have to parse all the calendar to add the date.

Here is a refactored version of your program :

```
while True:
    choice = input("Enter Q to quit, A to add a new event : ").upper()
    if choice == 'Q':
        print ("You have quitted this program")
        break #to quit the entire program
    elif choice == 'A':
        name = input ("Enter the name of an event you want to add : ")
        y= int(input("Enter the year of your event: "))
        m = int(input("Enter the month of your event: "))
        d = int(input("Enter the day of your event: "))
        h = int(input("Enter the hour of your event: "))
        mi = int(input("Enter the minute of your event: "))
        date = (y,m,d,h,mi)
        
        # Opening the file in append mode
        f = open("calendar.txt", 'a', encoding='utf-8')
        f.write('{},{},{},{},{},{}\n'.format(name, date[0], date[1], date[2], date[3], date[4]))
        f.close()
        
    print("------ ALL YOUR EVENTS ------")
    # Showing the entire calendar
    f = open("calendar.txt","r")

    for event in f.readlines():
        split = event.split(',')
        print("{} happens on {}/{}/{} at {}:{}".format(split[0],
                                                       int(split[1]),
                                                       int(split[2]),
                                                       int(split[3]),
                                                       int(split[4]),
                                                       int(split[5])
                                                       ))
    print('-----------------------------')
```

And the output :

```py
Enter Q to quit, A to add a new event : A
Enter the name of an event you want to add : Christmass
Enter the year of your event: 2020
Enter the month of your event: 12
Enter the day of your event: 25
Enter the hour of your event: 0
Enter the minute of your event: 0
Christmass,(2020, 12, 25, 0, 0)
My birthday,(1997, 1, 1, 6, 45)


C:\Users\tcravic\Downloads>python test.py

C:\Users\tcravic\Downloads>python test.py
Enter Q to quit, A to add a new event : A
Enter the name of an event you want to add : Christmass
Enter the year of your event: 2020
Enter the month of your event: 12
Enter the day of your event: 25
Enter the hour of your event: 0
Enter the minute of your event: 0
------ ALL YOUR EVENTS ------
Christmass happens on 2020/12/25 at 0:0
-----------------------------
Enter Q to quit, A to add a new event : A
Enter the name of an event you want to add : My Birthday
Enter the year of your event: 1997
Enter the month of your event: 03
Enter the day of your event: 01
Enter the hour of your event: 6
Enter the minute of your event: 45
------ ALL YOUR EVENTS ------
Christmass happens on 2020/12/25 at 0:0
My Birthday happens on 1997/3/1 at 6:45
-----------------------------
Enter Q to quit, A to add a new event : q
You have quitted this program
```

You can also read about [CSV format](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and [CSV parsing in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).